# How is the verb "proxy" determined in the audit logs?

Tags: kubernetes

According to the kubernetes documentation, those are the following verbs:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb
[image]

I've been looking at kubernetes-dashboard Role, and i saw this:

```
  - apiGroups:
    - ""
    resourceNames:
    - heapster
    - dashboard-metrics-scraper
    resources:
    - services
    verbs:
    - proxy
```

This is the role of kubernetes-dashboard

I didn't see any indication that in the audits they use the "proxy" verb. Any clearance would be great

Answer (score 1):

When you perform `kubectl proxy` the request goes to API Server which calls `POST /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/services/{name}/proxy` the proxy api of services as documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#-strong-proxy-operations-service-v1-core-strong-).

Proxy is not a verb, it's a sub resource exposed by Kubelet.

Comment: Are there any more non standard verbs? Is it possible to extend the API as such and map a non standard verbs to standard ones?

Comment: The correct way to extend kubernetes is to write a custom controller and implement your own custom resource.

Comment: I'm aware of it, i'm just wondering if it's possible to write custom verbs (as i'm trying to map all possible verbs)

Comment: I don't think its possible

Comment: actually i just saw a "use" verb under eks -> eks:podsecuritypolicy:privileged, not sure how it's mapped aswell..

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb